# Git revert is overwriting my files

Tags: git, commit, git-reset, git-revert

Say I make a bunch of changes to my files locally, then add these changes to the staging index and then commit them. Then I realise that actually, I've made some mistakes, and I want to quickly undo that whole commit and get back to where I was right before I committed (ie with my changes out of the repo and back in the index).

I tried to do a `git revert SHA` and this did indeed undo my most recent commit, but it also completely overwrote all my files and put them back into their original state.

How do I revert a commit without it overwriting my changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `git reset --soft <last commit you want to keep>`.

Note however that unlike `revert`, this will undo all of the commits after the one you specify (e.g. if you have `A-B-C-D (HEAD)` and you `git reset --soft B`, both `C` and `D` will be undone, with both of their changes left in the index).

---

Of course, another option is to not undo your last commit, but instead just modify it to get rid of the mistakes. You can do this via `git commit --amend`, which acts just like `git commit` except that instead of creating a new commit, it modifies (amends) the latest existing commit.

```
git commit -m "this commit has mistake(s)"
...edit the file(s) with mistake(s)...
git add <file>
git commit --amend -m "same commit, no mistake(s)"
```